# showing user with multiple roles discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

with this command set to only one role. I want to set more than one role. how can I do it ?

````
let rolid = "663047983675342849"; 
  let tokuchi = client.guilds
    .get(sunucuid)
    .roles.get(rolid)
    .members.filter(o => !o.voiceChannel).map(member => member.user); 

 .setDescription(tokuchi.join("\n"))```
````

Comment: Your question is not very clear, to establish roles for what, what needs to be done with these roles?

Comment: im trying to when i write  prefix+names to list the names of those who are not in the voice in the role I have specified. [link](https://hasteb.in/isiyeret.js) thats all of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all members with multiple role somethink like this, but other code shown leaves questions

```
    let sGuild = client.guilds.get(sunucuid)
    let membersWithRoles = sunucuid.members.filter(member => {
        return member.roles.some(r=>['ROLEID','ROLEID'].includes(r.id))
    })

console.log(membersWithRoles)
```

**v2 version** 
At the fist you dont need get guild in all comands, use `message.guild` for this.

This code will return array of users usernames with any of your roles and if they dont have voiceconnection now.

```
exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    if(message.channel.type === 'dm') return
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR"))
      return message.channel.send(" Missing Permission");
      let tokuchi = message.guild.members.filter(member => {
        return member.roles.some(r=>['ROLEID','ROLEID'].includes(r.id)) && !member.voiceChannel
    }).map(member => (member.user.username))

  const basarili = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor('RANDOM')
      .setAuthor(`Seste Olmayan Yetkililer`, client.user.avatarURL)
      .setDescription(tokuchi.join("\n"))
      .setFooter("Created by Tokuchi")
      .setTimestamp()
      .addField(`İşlemi Gerçekleştiren Kişi:`, `${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`)
  return message.channel.send(basarili)


  };
```

its return a users.username because you cant `.join('\n)` users, its a collection, not array.

Comment: i think this command not working  [link](https://hasteb.in/isiyeret.js) for this command

Comment: You need to get users who have 1 of any roles and not in voicechannel now, right?